# Where is Publish command in VS2017 project menu?

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017

VS2017 enterprise ([about info](http://pastebin.ca/3784847))

I do following:

```
mkdir test
cd test
dotnet new mvc
dotnet restore
dotnet build
```

Then I open test.cspoj and want to publish app:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By default some extensions in `Tools>Extensions and Updates` are disabled, so Pusblish feature is unavailable.